# In Javascript how to compare and store the values dynamically like Key and value object

Tags: javascript, jquery

In javascript arrays i need to check and assign the values in array like key and value pair .

**For example :**

if i added some values in the array and the second time the same value is retrieving one more time at that time i need to compare my array and i need to increment the previous value instead of storing the value in the array.please suggest me how to achieve this through javascript or jQuery

Answer (score 3):

In sounds like you want something like a hash table. In JavaScript you should use *objects* for this:

```
var data = {};

data['key'] = 5;

// later

data['key'] += 10; // data['key'] is now 15
```

More information about objects in [*MDC - Working with Objects*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

If you want to associate data with an *HTML element*, then have a look at jQuery's [`.data()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method (which uses objects too, so in any case you have to learn about them ;))

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you want to check if a given value already exists in an Array and if so, you want to increment that value by... "one" I guess ?

```
var foo = [10, 7, 44, 12, 102, 5],
    pos = foo.indexOf(44);

if( pos > -1 ) {
    foo[pos]++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you can encapsulate the function which counts the numbers of occurrences of the values and the object in which the counts are stored:

```
var count = function() {
  var counts = {};
  return function(key) { if (typeof counts[key]=="number") counts[key]++; else counts[key]=1; return counts[key]; };
}();

document.write(count("a"));   // 1
document.write(count("b"));   // 1
document.write(count("a"));   // 2
```

Comment: Don't use arrays with non-numerical indexes... *edit:* numerical is ok ;)

Comment: It won't be a numbers it's like the alpanumeric characters